# Handling null in custom cast operator

Tags: c#, casting, explicit

I am trying to add a cast from a `class` to a `struct`.

In my concrete case, the to-be-casted source type would be `class MacAddress`, a class used for string-input validation of the various typical 6-byte-notations such as `0a:3f…` or `0A-3F…`, conversion of such strings to a byte-array, offering formatted ToString, etc.

The target type would be `readonly struct BluetoothAddress`, a wrapper for the rather unhandy `ulong` that the `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` APIs return or require, providing `DebuggerDisplay`, etc.

In principle, every *non-null* instance of `MacAddress` will always represent a sequence of any 6 bytes, which can always unambiguously seed a `BluetoothAddress` struct. Therefore, if I wanted to allow passing a "user-input wrapping `MacAddress`" into functions that require an "`ulong`-wrapping `BluetoothAddress`", I would need an `implicit` cast like this:

```
public static implicit operator BluetoothAddress(MacAddress macAddress) {
    var bytes = macAddress.ToByteArray();
    ulong Shift(int i) => ((ulong) bytes[i]) << ((5 - i) * 8);
    ulong value = Shift(0) | Shift(1) | Shift(2) | Shift(3) | Shift(4) | Shift(5);
    return new(value);
}
```

There's just one problem: accessing `.ToByteArray()` would throw NRE if `macAddress` was `null`.

[Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/operator-overloads#conversion-operators) say "DO NOT throw from implicit casts." and "DO throw System.InvalidCastException if a call to a cast operator results in a lossy conversion and the contract of the operator does not allow lossy conversions."

So, how should the cast operator in `BluetoothAddress` be designed?

1. Throw an `InvalidCastException` if `macAddress` is `null`?
2. Throw an `ArgumentNullException(nameof(macAddress))`?
3. Let the framework throw the `NullReferenceException`?
4. try-catch the NRE and pass it on as inner exception of my own `InvalidCastException`?
5. …?

And should it be `explicit` (because it can throw), or can it still be `implicit`, because my cast operator will never throw unless you're trying to cast `null` to this *value* type (so a throw shouldn't be too unexpected)?

Comment: Maybe you should just not create an explicit cast in this case, and use other means (static method etc). I would be very surprised if my explicit cast failed because `Length` is not 6.

Comment: You start asking one thing (cast nulls to something) then ask a different thing (the cast can only be performed if the value of int SourceClass.Length { get; } is 6.). That's not a cast, that's a transformation

Comment: in other words: write your own `ConvertTo`-method or a copy-constructor, instead of using a cast. Apart from this casting `null` to a (nullable) reference-type shouldn't throw anything. You can surely write `(MyClass)null`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Accessing source.Length would cause a NRE, so the problem arises if `source` is null.

Comment: @Evk it is an obvious attempt to inject the business logic into casting. The next developer will be happy )))

Comment: but then the problem isn't that you're checking for length==6, but that you're accessing source.

Comment: @LWChris that doesn't change the fact you have a transformation or mapping, not a cast. In any case, if the target type is nullable you can return a null. If not, throw because you can't just convert a missing value (what null represents) to a specific value. The cast operator itself should check for nulls and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if a null isn't allowed

Comment: So I take it casting null to any reference type should just work, casting null to any value type should throw `ArgumentNullException`, and accessing members probably means the two types aren't in the same domain and you should refrain from defining a cast altogether in favor of transformation methods, i. e. static "FromSource" on the target side or "ToTarget" on the source side.

Comment: @Evk I reworked the whole question, because my class-2-class example was stupid. Obviously, casting null to any other reference type can simply succeed by returning null and doesn't need member access. In my case, target is a struct. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain My bad, class-2-class was a bad example. I reworked the question.

Comment: Maybe make MacAddress also a struct? If not then I'd avoid implicit cast, and if you insist to use a cast - I'd use explicit and throw InvalidCastException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *rule* that says you can't throw on `null` when casting between classes, but you probably shouldn't, aside from the general discussion of whether using casts for this kind of operation is a good idea if "interesting" logic is involved (it probably isn't).

`null` is a valid value for any reference type (nullable reference types notwithstanding, as these are just annotations), regardless of how it's constructed. Throwing an `InvalidCastException` when converting a `null` introduces inconsistencies, as no built-in conversion operator between reference types does that. In particular, consider the fact that `(TargetClass) (object) default(SourceClass)` compiles and runs successfully, whereas `(TargetClass) default(SourceClass)` would not, under the proposed semantics.

Conversion between value types is a different matter: because `null` is not a valid value for any value type (except `Nullable`, but more on that later) you'll never run into this problem casting *from* value types. If casting *to* a value type from a reference type, then either `InvalidCastException` or `NullReferenceException` would be appropriate -- the former because we're in a cast, the latter because it's what the runtime itself produces when attempting this with no user-defined conversion. `ArgumentNullException` is technically also correct, though confusing to the caller, as it doesn't appear as an argument at the call site.

Finally, for nullable value types, consider that `(TargetClass) default(SourceStruct?)` is valid and bypasses your operator altogether, producing a `null` value. This, too, argues against throwing an exception for the `null` case from your own operator.

Comment: Hi, indeed I just realized my example was bad because it asked class-2-class and that one's trivial for `null`. I am working on `class-2-struct`, therefore I reworked the question.

Comment: About the `ArgumentNullException`: I agree, but also there is this guideline that says you should use `ArgumentNullException(nameof(value))` inside property setters, where there is also no actual "argument named value" to be seen at the calling location.

Comment: I stand by what I said in my answer about casting to value types from reference types, which is your case. I think the advice for property setter is OK, in the sense that it's much more common for a property to encapsulate logic and callers would understand that a method is getting called if anything is failing. Even there I'd personally probably prefer an `InvalidOperationException`, but I could see it go either way, depending on your code base.

Comment: I think I will throw my own NullReferenceException. That way the code doesn't look like I forgot to check, but you get the same behavior as when the framework does it when writing `(int) (object) null`.